How to import spatial matrix weight to Stata
I've created spatial matrix weights by using Geoda, but when I imported this .gal file to Stata by spmat command, the error i got is: Error in row 1 of spatial-weighting matrix
How to deal with this problem.

Can you point us to the documentation online for how to read a .gal file into Stata? I can't find anything geoda/stata weights related except this mailing list post on Geoda's GWT format... https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-10/msg01385.html
